# Using LINQ To Select Records Based on Child Collections item

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

i have instructor class.

```
public partial class Instructor
{
    public Instructor()
    {
        this.Courses = new HashSet<Course>();
        this.Courses1 = new HashSet<Course>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses1 { get; set; }
}
```

i want to search for instructor by name and course that he teaches 
i used predicate to build my condition 
but i need to access courses 1 collection inside instructor to get instructors whom teach this course but i can't

```
var Predict = PredicateBuilder.True<Instructor>();

        if (chkNameSearch.Checked)
        {
            Predict = Predict.And(ins => ins.FName == txtNameSearch.Text);
        }

        if (chkCourseSearch.Checked)
        {

            int CourseID=int.Parse(cmbCourseSearch.SelectedValue.ToString());
            Predict = Predict.And(ins => ins.Courses1.ID == CourseID);  //Error
        }
```

Comment: i can't  access ID property of Courses 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Courses1 doens't have any ID property. Try doing this:

```
Predict = Predict.And(ins => ins.Courses1.Any(c => c.ID == CourseID));
```

Comment: thanks so much ,i'm beginner with linq and found hard time :(

Comment: So did it fixed your problem? Please, accept the answer if it did :)